# Fuel cell power output

Tags: pressure, aerospace-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, experimental-physics, product-engineering

I've spent innumerable time over the years looking for commercially available hydrogen / oxygen fuel cells that might actually be usable in one project concept or another. The best I've ever managed to find was a cell stack about the size of a backpack. However its power output was a paltry 1 kW. I have sporadically found references to tests with and without a centrifugal blower. Which showed there was a tangible difference. But which still didn't even approach my power requirements.

Is there a stack available, or is it at least possible to feed a fuel sell stack with high pressure gas's to obtain higher power output?
More specifically is the relationship between input pressure linear with the power output of the stack?

Comment: 80 MPa would make these things bombs.  How about 20 backpack sized units tied together?  That's all an EV car battery is.  But back on task, Honda's Clarity fuel cell was about 100 kw.

Comment: `didn't even approach my power requirements` ... not very useful information ... please describe your requirement ... edit the post and add the info ... do not write a comment

Comment: I didn't include my exact requirements because I was trying to understand if the input pressure has a linear relationship with the power output of the stack. I wasn't really expecting people to do the engineering for me. The best stack I could find of appropriate form factor had an output of 1Kw. I however need 100Kw in the same form factor. So if the input pressure to output power is linear. I would need an input pressure of 100 Bar.

Comment: But is it that straightforward or am I missing something?